# WooCommerce Notices и кеширование

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, кэширование

Всем привет!

Что имеем:

1. WooCommerce + дочерняя тема на базе Storefront;
2. WP Rocket в качестве плагина кеширования + его же настройка для NGINX;

В чем проблема: различные уведомления от WooCommerce (те самые notices) работают некорректно.

Что происходит:

1. Вычищаем весь кеш;
2. С главной страницы добавляем товар в корзину (AJAX);
3. Пытаемся еще раз добавить товар в корзину, что в соответствии с
   настройками не разрешается (любой товар в корзине может быть только в 1
   экземпляре).
4. Происходит редирект на страницу товара, где отображается
   предупреждение, что товар есть в корзине.
5. Страница кешируется вместе с предупреждением и дальше показывается в
   таком виде в течении всего времени жизни кеша.

Нашел на просторах GitHub вот такое решение:

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rkt_notice_with_get', 1 );
function rkt_notice_with_get() {
    if ( function_exists( 'wc_notice_count' ) && wc_notice_count() > 0 && ! isset( $_GET['woonotice'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'woonotice', 'yes' ) );
        die();
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все логично: при редиректе проверяется наличие уведомлений и если уведомление есть, то добавляется параметр woonotice, соответственно страница не кешируется и все отлично.

Но если страница уже есть в кеше, то данное правило не работает. Как я понимаю свою лепту вносит WP Rocket, который отдает страницу минуя какие-то этапы самого WordPress. Но это не точно.

В общем вопрос такой: как все эти особенности кеширования учесть при работе с уведомлениями?

Comment: Выкинуть эту хрень (WP Rocket) и всё наладиться

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам себе могу предложить такое решение (может быть оно и другим пригодится).

Самый простой путь, который я придумал - это доставать все эти сообщения от WooCommerce с помощью AJAX и показывать либо где-то в нужном месте на странице, либо в виде всплывающих сообщений.

Для того, чтобы исключить вывод сообщений можно использовать следующие хуки:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form_cart_notices', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_lost_password_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'before_woocommerce_pay', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_reset_password_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
```

Этот список соответствует [документации WooCommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php)

Далее соответственно пишем код для AJAX, в котором получаем все сообщения с помощью

```
    $notices = wc_get_notices();
    wc_clear_notices();
```

Таким образом мы можем показать все задуманные разработчиками сообщения, при этом не ломая логику кеширования плагинами.